# AngularJS how can I call functions after multiple ajax requests are succeeded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using for loop to send ajax requests to delete multiple items in datatables. Is there any way I can call functions after all the requests are succeeded? Calling functions after every request bring some issues for my datatables, also it's not working if calling functions outside of loop cause they're asynchronous requests

```
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedRows.length; i++) {
      $http({
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: $scope.url + '/' + $scope.selectedRows[i].name + '?recursive=true'
      })
      .then(function(res) {
       // $scope.clearSelect();
       // $scope.dtInstance.rerender();
       // $mdDialog.hide();
      }, function(res) {
        console.log('error');
      })
    }
```

Comment: its bad idea to send multiple request to delete rows, you should consider updating api to accept multiple `ids` something like `DELETE /post?ids=1,3,5,7,8...` etc. this way can delete in one request

Comment: Why don't you make only one ajax request to delete all the record and then in the completion of ajax make another ajax call. Because looping ajax call is not good solution

Comment: Using a rest call inside a loop is a very bad practice. it should be one function that deletes all on the server side.

Comment: use `$q.all[<promise1>,<promise2> ..]` method. It will finish when ALL aync call will finish

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions guys, I'm doing front end only. I'll discuss this with my colleague if it can't be resolved well at my end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should collect the promises of the requests and use the

```
$q.all(promises).then(...)
```

Look here: [wait for all $http requests to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931846/wait-for-all-http-requests-to-complete-in-angular-js)

Comment: Look here: [wait for all HTTP requests to finish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931846/wait-for-all-http-requests-to-complete-in-angular-js)