# Recursive $http.get in for loop

Tags: angularjs, http, for-loop, asynchronous, promise

I use Angular 1.5. I have a function that queries Categories, then for each category, it queries Products. I want to show a message after all the products are retrieved, how many were retrieved. It outputs 0. What is the solution?

```
function getProducts() {
  vm.categories = [];
  var prodcount = 0;

  $http.get("localhost/menu/1/categories")
    .then(function(response) {
      var categories = response.data;
      angular.forEach(categories, function(cat) {
        $http.get("localhost/category/" + cat.id + "/products")
          .then(function(response) {
            cat.products = response.data;
            vm.categories.push(cat);
            prodcount += cat.products.length;
          });
      });
      $mdToast.show($mdToast.simple().textContent("retrieved " + vm.categories.length + " categories and, " + prodcount + " products!."));
    });
}
```

Comment: you don't have an endpoint to get all your products ?? this looks really weird and will surely affect your performance

Comment: you can use `$q.all` to wait for many promises to resolve, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931846/wait-for-all-http-requests-to-complete-in-angular-js. Also you may want to wait for every call to be done before doing the next one, in order to not over saturate your server. Best of course is to retrieve all in one server call instead of a client side loop.

Comment: I have always used a "provider" with AJAX requests in Angular.

Comment: MayK, you are right. I was trying to solve this and couldn't even think anything else. I'll make it one query to get everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at how asynchronous requests and promises works.
To make your code run you could do this:
    var promises = []; // Creates an array to store the promises

```
angular.forEach(categories, function(cat) {

    // Capture the promise
    var requestPromise = $http.get(...)
    .then(function(response) {
        ...
    });
    promises.push(requestPromise);  // Add it to the array
  });

  // This promise will be resolved when all promises in the array have been resolved as well.
  $q.all(promises).then(function(){
     $mdToast.show(...);
  })

});
```

But this approach is not quite good. You should try to minimize the amount of requests, doing only one preferably.

http://www.martin-brennan.com/using-q-all-to-resolve-multiple-promises/
http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Answer (score 1):

you can map your array of categories into an array of promises and then use `$q.all` to wait for them all to finish

```
function getProducts() {
    vm.categories = [];
    var prodcount = 0;

    $http.get("localhost/menu/1/categories")
            .then(function (response) {
                var categories = response.data;
                $q.all(categories.map(function (cat) {
                    return $http.get("localhost/category/" + cat.id + "/products")
                            .then(function (response) {
                                cat.products = response.data;
                                vm.categories.push(cat);
                                prodcount += cat.products.length;
                            });
                })).then(function () {
                    $mdToast.show($mdToast.simple().textContent("retrieved " + vm.categories.length + " categories and, " + prodcount + " products!."));
                });
            });
}
```