# Merge two json files with $.extend()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've got a function, where I load two local json files with `$http.get()`. After loading this files, I would like to merge it to one json file. I tried this with `$.extend()`, which I found in the JQuery Documentation.

Printing out my variables within the `$http.get()` calls, I can see in the console that my variables and my callback are correct. When I print the merged variable, it's still empty. Whats wrong?

**First JSON file:**

```
{
    "Default_Default_Add": "Hinzufügen",
    "Default_Default_AllInRibbon": "Alle im Band",
    "Default_Default_ApplicationMode_Development": "Entwicklung",
    "Default_Default_ApplicationMode_Education": "Schulung",
    "Default_Default_ApplicationMode_Production": "Produktion",
    "Default_Default_ApplicationMode_Testing": "Test",
    "Default_Default_Back": "Zurück"
}
```

**Second JSON files:**

```
{
    "Default_Return_Success": "Erfolg",
    "Success_Success_ChangePassword": "Passwort erfolgreich geändert",
    "Success_Success_DefaultRole": "Standardrolle wurde gesetzt",
    "Success_Success_Delete": "Erfolgreich gelöscht",
    "Success_Success_DeleteApplicationSetting": "ApplicationSetting erfolgreich gelöscht",
    "Success_Success_DeleteAscertainmentInstrument": "Erhebung erfolgreich storniert. "
}
```

**Function:**

```
loadData() {
    let json1: any;
    let json2: any;
    this.$http.get('../../app/shared/labels/default.de.json').success(function (data) {
        json1 = data;
        console.log(json1); //PRINT LINE 58
        console.log(data); //PRINT LINE 59
    });
    this.$http.get('../../app/shared/labels/success.de.json').success(function (data) {
        json2 = data;
        console.log(json2); //PRINT LINE 63
        console.log(data); //PRINT LINE 64
    });

    let json = $.extend({}, json1, json2);
    console.log(json); //PRINT LINE 68

    return json;
}
```

**Console prints:**
[image]

I think something goes in the wrong order or is to fast executed before everything was loaded, I have no idea. Hope for some help.

**!!! EDIT !!!:**

```
    let json1 = this.$http.get('../../app/shared/labels/default.de.json');
    let json2 = this.$http.get('../../app/shared/labels/success.de.json');
    let json: any;

    this.$q.all([json1, json2]).then(() => {
        let json = $.extend({}, json1, json2);
        console.log(json);
    });
```

Result:[image]

Comment: `get` calls are asynchronous which mean they will not wait to be completed before moving on and so the success callback is executed after your method returns `json`

Comment: @GillesC What's the best way to solve this? I expected something like this...

Comment: This has been solved many time on here, will try to find you a good example.

Comment: use the jQuery.Deferred() method

Comment: Seems like you use Angular. Try this and `extend` your JSONs in `all` promise. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931846/wait-for-all-http-requests-to-complete-in-angular-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for all $http requests to complete in Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931846/wait-for-all-http-requests-to-complete-in-angular-js)

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, you could take a look at $.Deferred object. Initialize two of them in the beginning of your function and once they are both finished, execute merge and return the result.

Comment: @GillesC I think this could solve it, but I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong with this solution. Please check my edit...

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144928/merge-two-json-files-with-extend maybe we can move to a chat @GillesC

Comment: Why this issue got a downvote? Can someone explain??

Answer (score 1):

Promises are resolved later. You are trying to merge jsons when they are not received yet. Try like below:

```
var mergedResult=null;
$.when( 
    this.$http.get('../../app/shared/labels/default.de.json'), 
    this.$http.get('../../app/shared/labels/success.de.json') )
  .done(function( json1, json2 ) {
       mergedResult = $.extend({}, json1, json2);        
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Deferreds](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/):

```
$.when( 
  this.$http.get('../../app/shared/labels/default.de.json'), 
  this.$http.get('../../app/shared/labels/success.de.json') 
).done( function( a1, a2 ) {
  json = $.extend({}, a1, a2);
});
```